# Ruby on Rails 3 Tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm going through the tutorial on http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ by Michael Hartl.

I'm on chapter six specifically code listing 6.27 which looks like this:

```
    require 'spec_helper'

    describe User do

      before do
        @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com", 
                         password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")
      end

      subject { @user }

      it { should respond_to(:name) }
      it { should respond_to(:email) }
      it { should respond_to(:password_digest) }
      it { should respond_to(:password) }
      it { should respond_to(:password_confirmation) }

      it { should be_valid }
    end
```

Now the User object looks like this:

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :email, :name, :password, :password_confirmation
      before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }

      validates :name, presence: true, length: {maximum: 50}
      VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
      validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, uniquenes  
      {case_sensitive: false}
    end
```

The User object has six attributes: id, name, email, created_at, updated_at, password_digest.
The password_digest is where the hashed password is stored.  But as you can see the fields password and password_confirmation are not in the database.  Only password_digest is.  The author claims we don't need to store them in a database but only create them temporarily in memory.  But when i run the code from the rspec test:

```
    @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com", 
                     password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")
```

I get an error telling me fields password and password_confirmation are undefined.  How do I get around this?

mike

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`attr_accessible` just tells Rails the properties are allowed to be set in mass-assignments, it doesn't actually create the properties if they don't exist.

You need to use `attr_accessor` for `password` and `password_confirmation` because these properties don't have corresponding fields in the database:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :password, :password_confirmation
  attr_accessible :email, :name, :password, :password_confirmation
  ...
end
```

Comment: rails guys need to do something to give attr_accessible a different name. .. I have seen so many guys confusing attr_accessor and attr_accessible

Comment: ok I found the problem.  I missed the line has_secure_password inside User class.  I don't know why or how this works.  Can someone please enlighten me?

Comment: You can see the source and documentation of [`has_secure_password` here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/secure_password.rb). It's a basic function which mixes a little bit of extra functionality into the model (an `attr_reader :password` and a setter which generates the encrypted password / password_digest automatically when the password property changes).